# Finding Documentation for Catia Libraries

Tags: c#, automation, catia

I'm fixing some issues at work with some macros that were created for CATIA a few years ago using C#, and I'm trying to find some more documentation on some of the libraries that are used to create them. Seems like libraries such as MECMOD, INFIFT, ProductStructureTypeLib, and KnowledgewareTypeLib are used the most. I've been using the CAA V5 Visual Basic Help that is inside the Program Files of CATIA, but that only seems to detail a small portion of the libraries used. These macros were created a few years ago, so I'm not sure if some functions have been renamed, or if I'm looking in the wrong place entirely. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please bear with me as I'm not too familiar with C# and am even less comfortable with CATIA automation, basically doing most of coding with Python.

Answer (score 1):

the *V5Automation.chm* includes almost everything that is possible via the COM Interface (API)